# Mapping Shift + Alt + anything in vim

Tags: vim

I would like to map Shift + Alt + l and Shift + Alt + h to switch between split in Vim (the default combinations are  Ctrl + w + l and Ctrl + w + h)

I have the solution to map Shift + Alt + "Arrow": it's :

```
map <A-S-Right> <ESC> <C-w>l (Shift + Alt + right arrow)

map <A-S-Left> <ESC> <C-w>h (Shift + Alt + left arrow)
```

But it's not working with the letter
i.e.

```
map <A-S-l> <ESC> <C-w>l

map <A-S-h> <ESC> <C-w>h
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: No, this actually appears to be a terminal limitation. (Sorry about the two deleted comments, they stopped making sense the second I posted them xd). Not entirely sure where the issue is, but it seems terminals are unable to pick up `<A-S-h>`. If you absolutely want to use those keybinds, you'll probably have to use gVim (which is basically the same thing, just without certain terminal limitations). Normal vim actually has [several limitations](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-Backspace_to_delete_previous_word) on keybinds, which are largely down to how terminals process input

Comment: Usually you don't need backslash escapes here. Also, why the `<ESC>`? You're already in Normal mode here... Try this instead: `nnoremap <A-S-Right> <C-w>l`

Comment: If I use `<C-v><A-l>` I get `<Esc>l`, and if I use `<C-v><A-S-l>` I get `<Esc>L` @Zoe; so I think it should be possible, at least in my terminal(?) I can't get mappings with `<A-l>` to work at all, but using `:nmap <Esc>l [..]` and `:nmap <Esc>L [..]` works. You could try this Fred. It would be useful if you could report what your terminals sends, I think there's a lot of variation across terminals on this, I never really looked at it as I don't like using the Alt key for mappings  Also `:help :map-alt-keys` might be useful.